# How to compare two array with specific field by using js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have 2 array a and b.

```
var a = [ [1,'jake','abc',0 ], ['r', 'jenny','dbf',0] , ['r', 'white','dbf',0] ]
var b = [ ['s','jake','abc' ], [3, 'peter','xyf'] , ['r', 'red','dbf',0] ]
```

Now, I only want to compare the second element in every item to get the difference. for example, ['s','jake','abc' ] in array b, I just want to compare the second element 'jake', whether it is the same with the second element of every item in array a. The expectation results should like this:

```
var resultAdd = [ [3, 'peter','xyf'],['r', 'red','dbf',0] ]
var resultMin = [ ['r', 'jenny','dbf',0],['r', 'white','dbf',0]  ]
```

Do I have to use double 'for loop' to get the results or any better way to get?
Thx!

Comment: Those are not even valid JS objects. Please show your actual code and what you've tried.

Comment: Still no idea what you are asking. Are you simply asking how to remove the first element of the array? Or what actually is the question *"compare the second field in every item to get the difference"* does not really describe anything.

Comment: @Ian: do these elements repeat in the arrays? like having multiple 'jake' on array a and array b ?

Comment: @ShivajiVarma : no, it is unique.

Comment: the second element is unique element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to remove items that exists on both arrays (i mean second element of each item matching).

Hope below code solves the problem.

```js
var a = [ [1,'jake','abc',0 ], ['r', 'jenny','dbf',0] , ['r', 'white','dbf',0] ]
var b = [ ['s','jake','abc' ], [3, 'peter','xyf'] , ['r', 'red','dbf',0] ]

var resultAdd = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));

var resultMin = a.filter(function(aItem){
  var i = resultAdd.findIndex(function(resultAddItem){return resultAddItem[1] == aItem[1];}); // checking second element of each item.
  if(i != -1){ // if element is present in resultAdd (clone of b)
    resultAdd.splice(i, 1); // Than remove it from the resultAdd.
    return false; // Also filter it out from resultMin.
  }
  return true;
})


console.log(resultAdd);
console.log(resultMin);
```

Comment: You may need a different solution if values are repetitive. Please accept the solution, if you are happy with it :)

Comment: Could you give me one more help?
I need to know the change of the third element if the second element is the same. for example:
  var a = [ [1,'jake','abc',0 ], ['r', 'jenny','dbf',0] , ['r', 'white','dbf',0] ]
  var b = [ ['s','jake','abc1' ], [3, 'peter','xyf'] , ['r', 'red','dbf',0] ]

  'jake' == 'jake' and 'abc'!='abc1'
so the expected result should be:
resultUpdated =  ['s','jake','abc1' ]    Great thx @ShivajiVarma